# Graph API delete all scores

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

As stated in the [Scores API documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/scores/):

> You can delete all the scores for your app by issuing an HTTP DELETE request to /APP_ID/scores with the app access_token for that app. This will reset the scores for your app. Use this if you'd like to periodically reset your game's scores and leaderboards.

So I go to Graph API Explorer and type /(APP ID OMITTED)/scores, Select DELETE method and paste in the app token I get from Access Token Tool in the access token field. I click submit and the following error is displayed:

```
"error": {
    "message": "An unknown error has occurred.", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 1
  }
```

If I paste in the user's token ID instead I get this:

```
"error": {
    "message": "(#15) This method must be called with an app access_token.", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 15
  }
```

What am I doing wrong?